# How to specify a range of numbers in a single cell

Tags: excel, range, lookup

Background: I am researching heavy metal contents in soil and i have a list of each specific heavy metal and its permissable concetration thresholds in the soil.

The problem is very specific:
Here is the problem... I need a range of numbers for example 0,85 - 1, to be specified in a single cell. So this single cell should contain a range, from which i can lookup a number within that range.

[image].

I am not sure if that is even possible in excel.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to concatenate cell values, is this what you want?

[image]

In order to do this, I have put the Excel formula `=B2 & " - " & C2` in cell "F2".

Obviously, you don't need to parse that result for checking if a value is within that range, as you can see in following screenshot, based on the formula `=AND(E2>=B$2,E2<=C$2)`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i already tried this and it does not solve my problem (at least not the whole problem) because i need to also be able to look those range values up. For example: if i type 0.9 in a cell, the index match function needs to know that this number is within this range from 0,85 - 1 (in your example F2 cell). This problem can actually be solved with if function but in order to look all those limit, warning and critical levels, i would many IFs nested. So im wondering, whether there exist a simpler solution than many IFs sentences nested together.

Comment: @gela: ... and what about my answer now?